# Generating Nested XML using oracle sql XMLElement function in oracle 19c

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I need to create a report but the output needs to be in XML format.

I'm following oracle docs, Example 18-3 XMLELEMENT: Generating Nested XML

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb13gen.htm#ADXDB1620,

```
SELECT XMLElement("record",
         XMLElement("PersonRegNumber", p.person_reg_number),
         XMLElement("first_name", p.first_name)
        ) AS "record"
FROM person p
where p.id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

but I'm not getting the desired output, more exactly I'm getting back **(XMLTYPE)**

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, any hints will be very appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: XMLType is correct.  What client software are you using? you should be able to drill down on that and see the XML.

Comment: @OldProgrammer right thanks, just noticed that. I'm using sql develor. How do I see the data? right now is hidden, I have to right click on the row to see it.

Comment: just double-click on the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also convert the XMLTYPE to a string if needed with the getClobVal() function:

```
SELECT XMLElement("record",
         XMLElement("PersonRegNumber", p.person_reg_number),
         XMLElement("first_name", p.first_name)
        ).getClobVal() AS "record"
FROM person p
where p.id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```